Black Screen For 20+ Second Before GRUB Menu Appears on Dual-Boot (Windows 11 and Ubuntu)
I have HP Laptop 15-fd0107TU with dual boot: Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
I'm experiencing a significant delay (over 20+ seconds) when i turn ON the laptop, where a black screen is shown before the GRUB menu appears. This issue started after I installed VirtualBox on my Ubuntu system. During the installation, I was prompted to configure Secure Boot and enter a password.
I’ve reinstalled both Windows and Ubuntu, wiping the SSD completely, i also disabled the secure boot and reset the bios, yet the problem still there.
Before installing VirtualBox, the system booted normally without this issue. What could be causing this delay, and how can I resolve it?
Update:
Updated:
I'm facing an unusual issue with my Laptop. When i shutdown the laptop and immediately turn it back ON, there's a delay of 20+ seconds and when i turn it ON after some time it just 5 seconds and I have noticed that my BIOS date and time are consistently set 5 hours behind my actual timezone even after a restart. I tried adjusting the BIOS clock manually, but every time I shutdown or even restart, it reverts back to being 5 hours behind. The clock does maintain time, but with this consistent offset.
The time sync issue occurs exclusively after using Ubuntu. Windows 11 successfully synchronizes the BIOS time, but each time I boot into Ubuntu, the BIOS clock becomes unsynchronized. This desynchronization also seems to be linked to the extended boot delay, which only happens when I use Ubuntu.
============================================================
Used systemd-analyze to check the boot process, and I found:
Startup finished in 36.206s (firmware) + 5.437s (loader) + 1.556s (kernel) + 6.786s (userspace) = 49.987s 
graphical.target reached after 6.777s in userspace.

============================================================
~$ systemd-analyze blame:

4.420s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.639s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 667ms NetworkManager.service
 572ms snapd.seeded.service
 544ms thermald.service
 318ms dev-nvme0n1p6.device
 298ms upower.service
 281ms snapd.service
 228ms apport.service
 192ms user@1000.service
 176ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
 151ms dev-loop5.device
 146ms dev-loop7.device
 143ms gpu-manager.service
 142ms dev-loop4.device
 137ms dev-loop6.device
 136ms rsyslog.service
 133ms udisks2.service
 128ms dev-loop3.device
 124ms gnome-remote-desktop.service
 122ms systemd-resolved.service
 118ms dev-loop2.device
 114ms polkit.service
 114ms apparmor.service
 113ms power-profiles-daemon.service
 110ms systemd-journald.service
 104ms dev-loop0.device
  98ms accounts-daemon.service
  90ms dev-loop1.device
  90ms bluetooth.service
  85ms grub-common.service
  82ms avahi-daemon.service
  82ms secureboot-db.service
  75ms systemd-modules-load.service
  73ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  72ms systemd-logind.service
  65ms systemd-oomd.service
  65ms keyboard-setup.service
  65ms systemd-udevd.service
  61ms ModemManager.service
  60ms e2scrub_reap.service
  59ms dbus.service
  59ms dev-loop9.device
  58ms dev-loop8.device
  58ms plymouth-start.service
  57ms systemd-binfmt.service
  55ms switcheroo-control.service
  51ms dev-loop10.device
  51ms dev-loop15.device
  50ms dev-loop14.device
  50ms dev-loop13.device
  49ms dev-loop12.device
  49ms dev-loop11.device
  47ms snapd.apparmor.service
  46ms dev-loop16.device
  44ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-F012\x2d6909.service
  43ms gdm.service
  42ms systemd-hostnamed.service
  38ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
  35ms systemd-remount-fs.service
  32ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  32ms packagekit.service
  28ms systemd-sysctl.service
  26ms colord.service
  24ms sysstat.service
  23ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
  22ms snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-286.mount
  22ms snap-core22-1564.mount
  21ms snap-core22-1621.mount
  21ms snap-firefox-4793.mount
  21ms snap-bare-5.mount
  20ms snap-firefox-5134.mount
  20ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
  20ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ffaa7268\x2dbbd3\x2d4191\x2da42d\x2d6e38a1458d43.swap
  20ms snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount
  19ms dev-hugepages.mount
  19ms snap-firmware\x2dupdater-147.mount
  18ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-176.mount
  18ms dev-mqueue.mount
  18ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
  17ms cups.service
  17ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
  17ms wpa_supplicant.service
  17ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1173.mount
  16ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
  16ms systemd-update-utmp.service
  16ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1218.mount
  15ms plymouth-read-write.service
  15ms snap-snapd-21759.mount
  15ms boot-efi.mount
  14ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-178.mount
  13ms kerneloops.service
  13ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
  13ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-253.mount
  13ms console-setup.service
  12ms modprobe@configfs.service
  12ms snap-thunderbird-507.mount
  12ms rtkit-daemon.service
  12ms ufw.service
  12ms modprobe@drm.service
  12ms kmod-static-nodes.service
  12ms snap-thunderbird-532.mount
  12ms sys-kernel-config.mount
  11ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
  11ms alsa-restore.service
  10ms modprobe@fuse.service
   9ms systemd-random-seed.service
   8ms snapd.socket
   7ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
   7ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
   6ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
   6ms systemd-rfkill.service
   5ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
   5ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
   5ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
   4ms openvpn.service
   4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
   3ms modprobe@loop.service
   1ms setvtrgb.service

============================================================
~$ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @6.777s
└─multi-user.target @6.777s
  └─kerneloops.service @6.762s +13ms
    └─network-online.target @6.744s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @2.323s +4.420s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1.645s +667ms
          └─dbus.service @1.570s +59ms
            └─basic.target @1.514s
              └─sockets.target @1.514s
                └─snapd.socket @1.505s +8ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1.502s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @2.814s +7ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @2.793s
                        └─system.slice @228ms
                          └─-.slice @228ms



I’m voting to close this question because since it is happening before the boot loader even loads, it has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Sorry, but this isn't on topic here. We can't help with processes that are upstream of Ubuntu loading. I suggest you delete this and ask instead on our sister site, [su].

While you are waiting, do you see a message such as "press F10 to enter BIOS"? On my HP there is a BIOS option to change the length of time during which this message is displayed. You can choose up to 20 seconds. If you see this message, go to the BIOS and reduce the length of time, because while this message is displayed the booting hangs (to give you time to hit the key if you want to).

No, its just a black screen, no message... and in bios i don't see any timing options.

If the firmware is not current, update it. The latest is version F.67 Rev.A and it was released as recently as August.
https://support.hp.com/sk-en/drivers/swdetails/hp-15s-du0000-laptop-pc/model/31057143/swItemId/ob-334748-1

@LiamProven I already updated it to the latest, its https://support.hp.com/sk-en/drivers/swdetails/hp-15.6-inch-laptop-pc-15-fd0000/model/2101497704/swItemId/ob-337078-1?sku=832T9PA , HP Laptop 15-fd0107TU (832T9PA) is my model

Good stuff. Few people bother to do this. On my work Dell in my previous job, a firmware update took over 2 minutes off the bootup time! Could it be that it is trying some device that is not present before it gets to your boot partition? Can you move the volume you want to be the default into first place?

@LiamProven I'm facing an unusual issue with my Laptop. When i shutdown the laptop and immediately turn it back ON, there's a delay of 20+ seconds and when i turn it ON after some time it just 5 seconds and I have noticed that my BIOS date and time are consistently set 5 hours behind my actual timezone even after a restart. I tried adjusting the BIOS clock manually, but every time I shutdown or even restart, it reverts back to being 5 hours behind. The clock does maintain time, but with this consistent offset.

The time sync issue occurs exclusively after using Ubuntu. Windows 11 successfully synchronizes the BIOS time, but each time I boot into Ubuntu, the BIOS clock becomes unsynchronized. This desynchronization also seems to be linked to the extended boot delay, which only happens when I use Ubuntu.

Linux assumes your system clock runs in UTC, and it applies an offset. Windows assumes your system clock runs on local time. This is normal, expected behaviour. https://superuser.com/questions/884278/time-wrong-when-dual-booting-windows-and-linux
